# Properly return value and print in html after a form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

How do I return the result from a post in the original html?

For example in my form, I submit an email address. After the email address is submited I would like to show that email back in a div and hide the form.

How can I do that using angularjs and php?

**simple HTML form**

```
<form name="EmailForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="mail_handler.php">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control size" ng-model="email.text" placeholder="me@example.com" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label ng-show="EmailForm.email.$valid"><input ng-model="IAgree" name="tos" required="required" type="checkbox" /> I have read and agree to the Terms of Service</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" ng-show="IAgree" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Spam me now!
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**and a simple php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: replace `header('Location: index.html')` with `echo "<div>".$email."</div>";`

Comment: @mplungjan hi, and thank you for your comment. That will only echo a <div>, i want to display a div in my html, the html where i do the post..

Comment: @stefan your comment sounds a bit confusing: the div you want to display in simple.php or index.html ?     if the later you have 2 problems 1.) header('.......... changes at which url you are but it does NOT retransmit the $_POST.   2.) it is a html page thus it won't be able to do php commands or process them

Comment: hi @Thomas, yes, I want to display the div in index.html, sorry for the confusion, english is not my native language.

Comment: Then try `$email = $_POST['email'];
    header('Location: index.html?email='.urlencode($email));` and use location.search in index.html to grab and show it

Comment: @stefan That is no problem that is why comments are also there to ask for clarifications :).  But that aside as its a .html you have the problem that it can't do php code inside (you would to have to rename it to .php)  and you can't use a post variable in there. So either you have to reanme it to a .php and give it email as post  OR you ahve to do a workaround like mplungjan mentions which would let you ahve index as .html still

Comment: @mplungjan, I tried your solution, and worked for me, thanks. If you decide to post your answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
header('Location: index.html?email='.urlencode($email));
```

you can in index.html do

```
window.onload=function() {
  var email = location.search?location.search.split("email=")[1]:"";
  document.getElementById("emailId").innerHTML=decodeURIComponent(email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two variants:

1. You should change the action of the form to "index.php" and put all the code for the form in index.php

2.In the other variant you will use everything you have done just change `header('Location: index.html');` with `header('Location: index.php/?email=' . urlencode($email));`

And then in index.php:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
echo '<div class="email">' . $email . '</div>';
```

Comment: You should change the homepage to a php extension in order it to work.

Comment: Is this not what I commented, except using index.html instead of php ?

Comment: @mplungjan, yes it is

Answer (score 1):

You can write both html and php in single php file. i.e form_submit.php
After create php file you can write following code in form_submit file.

```
 <form name="EmailForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="mail_handler.php">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control size" ng-model="email.text" placeholder="me@example.com" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label ng-show="EmailForm.email.$valid"><input ng-model="IAgree" name="tos" required="required" type="checkbox" /> I have read and agree to the Terms of Service</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" ng-show="IAgree" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Spam me now!
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    ?>
    </div>
       <style>
        .form-horizontal{display:none} 
<!-- above statement will hide form after submission of form -->
       </style>
    }
    ?>
```

After submit your form you will see email on same page in particular div.